# How to fetch value from parse class containing Array type column of strings in android

Tags: android, arrays, parse-platform

I have a class named `UserData` on parse.com, containing column name as `usersports` which is of array type,i successfully added strings in the array, but i got stuck while fetching the array values and displaying to a list.
say: parse array type is like this,

```
["Cycling","Diving","Equestrian"]
```

I have tested using `JsonArray` for parsing the array values from parse but not succeed. In my code getting `checkuserSportarray` as null. Please help me out.

Below is my code:

```
  private void userDetailfromParse(){

         ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Sportapp.USERDATA);
         query.whereEqualTo(Sportapp.USER_GOOGLE_ID, google_id_from_preference.trim());
         query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
         @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public void done(final ParseObject login_data, ParseException e) {
             if (login_data == null) {
                        Log.d("Data", "The getFirst request failed. in profile"+e.getCode());
                      }
                 else{
                     userEmail = login_data.getString(Sportapp.USER_EMAIL);
                     userName = login_data.getString(Sportapp.USER_NAME);                                       
                     userGender = login_data.getString(Sportapp.USER_GENDER);

                    checkuserSportarray = login_data.getJSONArray(Sportapp.USERDATA);

                    }                         

               }
             });
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure Sportapp.USERDATA contains `["Cycling","Diving","Equestrian"]`?

Comment: Sportapp.USERDATA is my class name, i have a column named usersports storing  ["Cycling","Diving","Equestrian"] which is of array type

Comment: So you're trying to create an array from your class name? Show us your login_data content

Comment: i already created array, in the code Snippet, i posted above, in that i am tying to fetch those string values from the array.

Comment: If checkuserSportarray is null that means that you are not "creating an array" like you're saying. I suggest you debug your login_data content and check it's structure. If you post it here it will be easier to help you

Comment: This is how i added on parse.
login_data.addAllUnique(Sportapp.USER_SPORTS,selected_sport_list);
         login_data.saveInBackground();

using this i successfully added string into the array.

Comment: We just need to know the content of `login_data` right before you call `login_data.getJSONArray(Sportapp.USERDATA);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

works fine for me:

```
    List<String> list11 =  new ArrayList<String>();

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> pQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("UserData");
    pQuery.whereEqualTo(Sportapp.USER_GOOGLE_ID, google_id_from_preference.trim());
    pQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
            if (e==null) {
            if (list.size()>0) {
                ParseObject p = list.get(0);
                if (p.getList("usersports")!=null) {
                    list11 =  p.getList("usersports");
                }
                else
                {
                    list11= null;
                }
                }}
                        }
                        });
```

use getList method to get the data from array column of parse table

```
now if you want to get all individual data of parsed array ,you can simply apply looping on **list11**.
```

For more info see this link: [Parse Object](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html)

Comment: i must vote up +1 for this, unfortunately i have less reputation,
thanks @userAndroid

Answer (score 1):

pass your column name in  getJSONArray method like this:-

```
checkuserSportarray = login_data.getJSONArray("usersports");
```