# Parse.com pull array data

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist, parse-platform

I'm making a friends list in Parse using an Array. I'm having trouble parsing the array within the users table. [image: Array Column]

How can I get each object in the array and display it's value?

Answer (score 3):

The above answer will terminate the app when the array will have null value.You have to check that the value of that perticular column is null or not .See below code

```
List<String> list11 =  new ArrayList<String>();
ParseQuery<ParseObject> pQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("TABLE NAME");
pQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
        if (e==null) {
        if (list.size()>0) {
            ParseObject p = list.get(0);
            if (p.getList("friendsArray")!=null) {
                list11 =  p.getList("friendsArray");
            }
            else
            {
                list11= null;
            }
            }}
                    }
                    });
```

use getList method to get the data from array column of parse table

```
now if you want to get all individual data of parsed array ,you can simply apply looping on **list11**.
```

For more info see following link:

[ParseObject](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html)

[How to fetch value from parse class containing Array type column of strings in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26057826/how-to-fetch-value-from-parse-class-containing-array-type-column-of-strings-in-a/26060924#26060924)

Comment: That is some awful code :S a simple check for null at getList() should be enough. I would much rather terminate as early as possible to avoid nested code and an extra query - just to find out that the list is not there

Answer (score 0):

Since the array is Pointers, they do not contain any data, thus you need to fetch the objects by doing something like this:

```
    List<ParseObject> objects = user.getList("friendsArray");
    if (objects == null)
        return;

    ParseObject.fetchAllIfNeededInBackground(objects, new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                return;
            }

            // friends are each filled with data 

        }
    });
```

As userAndroid correctly mention, if there is no values in 'friendsArray' it might return null:

> Returns null if there is no such key or if the value can't be converted to a List

This could be solved by checking if the key exists `user.has("friendsArray")`, I have updated the code to simply return if the objects list is null.

Comment: List<ParseObject> objects = user.getList("friendsArray"); this will terminate the app if the "friendsArray" has no value,will give the exception array mau not be null.